# Git bash black screen (windows)

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, git-bash

I am trying to access git bash, but nothing happens (black screen). I used git bash many times during September and October, but when I tried today it did this. What can I do to solve this?

Thanks.

[image: Git bash - black screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had Cygwin installed? I was having this exact issue, then I found out I still had a "etc" and "bin" directories in my user folder on Windows. After removing these (As I didn't want Cygwin) GitBash worked for me again :)

Comment: Yes I had cygwin, I'll take a look tonight!

Comment: I've removed the two directories, uninstalled git then reinstalled it and it is now working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as a temporary solution you could navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin using the windows cmd line and execute git.exe. For me Im able to perform gitbash functions, just not with the lovely unix like syntax and interface.
Also if you include gitbash to be written to your PATH during install, the win cmd line still works.