# issue with Git Bash

Tags: bash, installation, windows-10, git-bash

I am able to open git bash by typing "git bash" in the windows explorer URL space on one of my other laptop.

However, I'm trying to do it on another laptop of mine and it refuses to work. A black terminal opens for a split second and then disappears.

I've reinstalled it multiple times to no avail.

Currently using v2.27 of Git on Windows 10.

Any idea how I can get this working again? It's super convenient for me.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892725/git-bash-black-screen-windows?r=SearchResults

Comment: @matt No, it isn't similar. They're two different issues. My bash is working. It's just that I can't open it by typing "git bash" in the windows explorer URL

Comment: Can it work by typing `git-bash`? `git bash` invokes `git.exe` and `git-bash` invokes `git-bash.exe`.

Comment: @ElpieKay typing git-bash opens up a new tab in my web browser with the URL "git-bash/"

Comment: For what it's worth, I can reproduce the issue on my laptop. Windows 10, git version 2.25.windows.1 - typing git-bash does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In system variables the C:\Program Files\Git\cmd is added to Path.
To launch git-bash.exe (which is the program which will use git.exe internally)
directly from windows explorer address field, you need to make it findable in Path.

git-bash.exe is in  C:\Program Files\Git\   (notice the lack of cmd directory)

Comment: Amazing, thanks for that suggestion. I think in my previous installation, I might have unknowingly added it to the PATH variable. Works fine now :)